# unexpected end of stream error while downloading mp3 file

Tags: android

unexpected end of stream error while downloading mp3 file.
sometimes download amount of music then show unexpected end of stream error.
i read links from rss(XML_TAGS) of a website.

```
URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
conection.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),8192);

File directory = new File("/storage/sdcard/Music/");
directory.mkdir();
// Create MusicDir
File mypath = new File(directory, "profile.mp3");

// Output stream
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
total += count;
// publishing the progress....
// After this onProgressUpdate will be called
publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

// writing data to file
output.write(data, 0, count);0, count);
```